# React-Native using Components without render

Tags: gps, maps, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am new to react-native and am trying to build a Map component that relies on a GPS component. (I am actually not even sure if 'component' is the correct word)

I want to render the map using a UI, but I also need the GPS to get the location information.

Now, how can I create a GPS class including all the GPS logic, calling only a single function to update the location on the page page? Or more specifically, how can I separate the GPS code into a new file without having to call a `<GPSComponent />` within the render method of the map-component?

To be more specific with the code example, I put it on CodePen here https://codepen.io/yeni/pen/WOrjJx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your GPS class in a separate file. The class should **not** extend Component.

Then import your GPS class in your UI Component (e.g. `import gps from './gps'`) and use it :)

Comment: thanks for the answer! how do I have to manage the clearWatch flag then however? in the end, the gps cannot rely on componentWillUnmount anymore

Comment: hm.. most simple way I'd try:
put the clearWatch in a cleanup() method or sth. of the gps class und call that method in the componentWillUnmount of the UI Components that uses the gps class.
(Disadvantage: you have to manually make sure, that the cleanup is called in every UI component that uses the gps class)

basically:
- for your componentDidMount: think of it as the constructor (or sth. like an initialize method) in your new class

- for your componentWillUnmount: think of it as the destructor (or sth. like an cleanup method, since destructors don't exist in es6) in your new class

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I understand there is no 'natural way' to do it and will try to implement it the way you proposed! :)

Answer (score 1):

another possible way is to return null inside render method

```
export default class GPSComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        // Do some stuff
    }

    someFunctions() { ... }

    render(){
        return null;
    }
}
```